# What's a simple way to web-ify my command-line daemon?

Tags: ajax, comet, push, server-push, websocket

Suppose I have a simple daemon type script that I run on my webserver.
I run it in a terminal, with gnu screen, so I can keep an eye on it.
That works fine (incidentally, I use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075947/can-i-use-gnu-screen)).

But now suppose I'd like to make a web page where I can keep an eye on my script's output.
What's the easiest way to do that?

Notes:

- This is mainly for myself and a couple co-hackers so if websockets is the answer and it only works on Chrome or something, that's acceptable.
- This question is asking something similar: [How to make all connected browsers reload initiated by a server-side event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964494/how-to-make-all-connected-browsers). But I'm hoping for a simpler, quick-and-dirty solution, and especially a general way to quickly do this for any script I might want to keep an eye on from a browswer.

Answer (score 1):

Let your daemon log output into a place that is accessible from a web script (Such as a database table), which can then display it. Have the webpage update once every few seconds. (You can get fancy at do it with `XmlHttpRequest` and Javascript, if you want)

### Edit:

Simplest way to have a page update, is with a [`meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`](http://www.google.com/search?q=meta+refresh) tag. A bit more elegant is to use Javascript - You can use something like [PeriodicalUpdater for jQuery](http://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/).

These solutions are both polling techniques. There is a trick you can pull to make the event propagate instantly, called comet. But that's a bit more complicated, and frankly a poll probably suits your use case fine.

Comment: Yeah, the daemon script is already running on the webserver and can send its output anywhere.  So I guess the question is, can you spell out how to have a web page update every few seconds (or better, whenever the daemon outputs something new)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks really promising (thanks to my friend and hacker extraordinaire, [David Yang](http://twitter.com/dyng)):

http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket